# find and display the sum of the cubes of the first n natural numbers

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to find and display the sum of the cubes of the first n natural numbers and with what code i have currently i can only seem to print up to the range that i want.

Being the max is 20 and it prints the cubes of my number up to 20. The loops that i write for the sum do not work and normally crash the program.

Any help or ideas on how to make it so the program only cubes up to the number that is input and then sum those cubes would be appreciated, please keep it simple.

```
public class MyIntNumberr
{ // construct a myintnumber with one instance field n
    public MyIntNumberr(int n)
    {
        number = n;
    }

    public void calcCubeAndSum(int num)
    {

        if (num < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("that integer is invalid please try again");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (num >= 1 && num <= 20)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + num + "      " + Math.pow(num, 3));
            num = num + 1;
        }

    }

    // instance fields
    private int number;
}


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyIntNumberTestt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number, num;

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a value to cube and gather  the sum of");
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);

        MyIntNumberr richard = new MyIntNumberr(num);

        richard.calcCubeAndSum(num);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where you accumulate the sum of the cubes...

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    System.out.print("Enter a value to cube and gather the sum of: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    calcCubeAndSum(num);
}

private static void calcCubeAndSum(int num) {
    if (1 <= num && num <= 20) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (num <= 20) {
            // Calculate the cube
            int cube = num * num * num;

            // Accumulate the cube into a sum
            sum += cube;

            // Display current result
            System.out.println("Current number: " + num + "\tCubed: " + cube + "\tCurrent Sum: " + sum);

            // Go to the next number
            num++;
        }
        // Display Total Sum
        System.out.println("Total Sum: " + sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("That integer is invalid please try again");
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HERE IS A SIMPLE WAY TO FIND N NATURAL NUMBERS USING PYTHON**
hope you all like it....

```
n = int(input("Enter the value of n:"))
for i in range (1,n+1):
    print(i)
```

**ANSWER**

```
Enter the value of n:10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: I am not sure if original post looking for a python answer.